# Angular reload data for ng-repeat without ugly refresh all items?

Tags: angularjs

I do have a message system where all the inbox messages are displayed:

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in inbox.messages">
// here the message 
</div>
```

Works fine. Now i want to use a polling system to get possible new messages, sent by other users. I wrote a pollingService with this piece of code:

```
$timeout(function() {
            $rootScope.inbox = MessagesInbox.get();           
            self.run();
        }, 10000);
```

Now each 10 seconds, the messages are pulled with ajax and are assigned to inbox. Now the ng-repeat updates... But it is ugly because is is rendered again and thus blinking the page.

Is there a way to update my messages another way, so that it will look neat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a comparison of what is currently in the inbox vs. what comes back from the service, and then add/delete/edit only those records that have changed.